# How to add new panels to the existing gutenberg document sidebar?

Tags: wordpress, panel, sidebar, wordpress-gutenberg

I try **to add two new panels to the existing gutenberg document sidebar**. One should contain a radio-button menu to set the height of the header image, and the other one a text-field to enter a subtitle for the page.

But because I do not want to use the outdated meta boxes technologie, there aren't hardly any tutorials how to accomplish this. I only found the following piece of code, but I have no idea how to shape it to my needs and where to put it ;) - My knowledge of coding is just not good enough, but I still need to implement this feature in my theme.

```js
const { registerPlugin } = wp.plugins
const { PluginDocumentSettingPanel } = wp.editPost

const PluginDocumentSettingPanelDemo = () => (
    <PluginDocumentSettingPanel
        name="custom-panel"
        title="Custom Panel"
        className="custom-panel"
    >
        Custom Panel Contents
    </PluginDocumentSettingPanel>
)
registerPlugin('plugin-document-setting-panel-demo', {
    render: PluginDocumentSettingPanelDemo
})
```

Do you maybe have a guess how to achieve my idea? Thanks for you support, and greetings from Austria! Samuel

Answer (score 1):

First of all, register the meta fields, so you have where to save the values. This goes in your plugin file or `functions.php`.

```
register_post_meta('post', 'customname_meta_subtitle', array(
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'type' => 'string',
    'single' => true
));

register_post_meta('post', 'customname_meta_header_height', array(
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'type' => 'string',
    'single' => true
));
```

You can check the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_meta/). We are telling WordPress to create 2 new post meta fields, with keys `customname_meta_subtitle` and `customname_meta_header_height`, which we will use in the Gutenberg part.

For the ES code, you will need the following:

```
const { registerPlugin } = wp.plugins
const { PluginDocumentSettingPanel } = wp.editPost
const { RadioControl, TextControl } = wp.components
const { withState } = wp.compose
const { withSelect, withDispatch } = wp.data

let SubtitleControl = ({ subtitle, handleSubtitleChange }) => (
    <TextControl
        label="Set subtitle"
        value={subtitle}
        onChange={subtitle => handleSubtitleChange(subtitle)}
    />
);

SubtitleControl = withSelect(
    (select) => {
        return {
            subtitle: select('core/editor').getEditedPostAttribute('meta')['customname_meta_subtitle']
        }
    }
)(SubtitleControl);

SubtitleControl = withDispatch(
    (dispatch) => {
        return {
            handleSubtitleChange: (value) => {
                dispatch('core/editor').editPost({ meta: { customname_meta_subtitle: value } })
            }
        }
    }
)(SubtitleControl);

let HeaderImageHeightControl = ({ height, handleHeightChange }) => (
    <RadioControl
        label="Set image height"
        help="Set the height of the header image"
        selected={height}
        options={[
            { label: '100', value: '1' },
            { label: '200', value: '2' },
        ]}
        onChange={handleHeightChange}
    />
);

HeaderImageHeightControl = withSelect(
    (select) => {
        return {
            height: select('core/editor').getEditedPostAttribute('meta')['customname_meta_header_height']
        }
    }
)(HeaderImageHeightControl);

HeaderImageHeightControl = withDispatch(
    (dispatch) => {
        return {
            handleHeightChange: value => {
                dispatch('core/editor').editPost({ meta: { customname_meta_header_height: value } })
            }
        }
    }
)(HeaderImageHeightControl);

const PluginDocumentSettingPanelDemo = () => (
    <PluginDocumentSettingPanel
        name="custom-panel"
        title="Custom Panel"
        className="custom-panel"
    >
        <SubtitleControl />
        <HeaderImageHeightControl />
    </PluginDocumentSettingPanel>
)
registerPlugin('plugin-document-setting-panel-demo', {
    render: PluginDocumentSettingPanelDemo
})
```

Most of this code is described in the [official WP tutorial](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/plugin-sidebar-0/), but feel free to ask if anything is unclear.

Finally, to use the new values, you can do something like this:

```
<h1><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'customname_meta_subtitle')[0]; ?></h1>
<h1><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'customname_meta_header_height')[0]; ?></h1>
```

This is to be used in the post template file, for the front-end visualization of the meta field info.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for the work you did!!

But unfortunately at least one error occures in the js file.

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

This error message is related to this part of the code:



let SubtitleControl = ({ subtitle, handleSubtitleChange }) => (
    <TextControl
        label="Set subtitle"
        value={subtitle}
        onChange={subtitle => handleSubtitleChange(subtitle)}
    />
);


I described the problem more detailed in a new answer above (since I did not know there exists the possibility to write a comment directly ;)

Comment: I ran the JavaScript through a Babel compiler, and the panel shows, but data does not save or update. Any reason why?